# Ios show/hide views inside a tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I have a tableview with a custom cell. Below image shows the view hierarchy of my tableview cell.

[image]

When adding rows to the tableview I'm hiding the 'check Image' imageview using below code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "accountCell", for: indexPath) as! AccountsTableViewCell

            cell.checkImage.isHidden = true

        return cell
    }
```

and when a row is clicked I'm showing the imageview again. Below is the code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "accountCell", for: indexPath) as! AccountsTableViewCell

        cell.checkImage.isHidden = false
    }
```

But the problem is when I click a row nothing happens. system execute the `cell.checkImage.isHidden = false` code line, but the imageview doesn't appear. It is still hidden. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: please reload your tableview after click the row

Comment: You can't dod it like that.  You need to update the checked/unchecked status somewhere (I suggest using a `Set<IndexPath>`) and then check that in your `cellForRowAt` - In `didSelectRowAt` you toggle the checked/unchecked status in your `Set` and then reload the affected cell.

Comment: @Nazmul Hasan reloading the tableview didn't work for me

Comment: @udi where you reload the tableview

Comment: @Paulw11 could you please explain it bit more.

Comment: @nazmulHasan  after the 'cell.checkImage.isHidden = false' line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't track cell checked status in your cell itself; the cell object is just a view onto your data and cells will be reused when the table view scrolls.

I suggest using a `Set<IndexPath>`.  In your `cellForRowAt` you can check the contents of the set in order to determine whether the checkmark should be hidden:

```
var checked = Set<IndexPath>()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "accountCell", for: indexPath) as! AccountsTableViewCell

    cell.checkImage.isHidden = self.checked.contains(indexPath)

    return cell
}
```

in your `didSelectRowAt` you simply toggle the set membership and reload the row

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if self.checked.contains(indexPath) {
        self.checked.remove(indexPath) 
     } else {
        self.checked.insert(indexPath)
     }

    tableView.reloadRows(at:[indexPath], with:.fade)
}
```

Comment: 'self.checked.contains(indexPath) ? self.checked.remove(indexPath) : self.checked.insert(indexPath)' gives a compilation error for me.

Comment: @udi what is your swift version ?

Comment: @NazmulHasan swift 4

Comment: Compilation error is: Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'IndexPath?' and '(inserted: Bool, memberAfterInsert: IndexPath)'

Comment: Sorry. Fixed that

Answer (score 3):

You have to manage your array (datasource)! when you click your row, update your array for that index and reload your table view.

Example :

Your array should have some flag like `isChecked` toggle it's value from true to false or vice-versa.

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check this flag and show or hide your image according to that flag!

Comment: your solution also working. Unfortunately I can accept only one answer. But thanks for your support.

Answer (score -1):

first be sure your

```
 tableview.delegate = self
```

second thing in did select row at index use that code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! AccountsTableViewCell


    cell.checkImage.isHidden = false
}
```