# How to show hide textview on tableView and change the height of tableView according to condition in swift 4?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uitextview, swift4

Hello i have a tableView with various "views" like userProfileView, SocialView etc. At the bottom of the table there is two views one is "commentViewDescription" and "commentBoxView". If comment data is blank then i want to load the tableview without "commentViewDescription" and if the comment data is not blank i want to load the tableView with "commentViewDescription". This can be done in the tableView delegate(heightforrowat), but the problem is when i write something on "commentBoxView" i want to show the "commentViewDescription" and want to increase the tableView height, .please some one help me regarding this matter, how to increase the tableView height

Comment: I think this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048272/ios-show-hide-views-inside-a-tableview-cell This works for me.

Comment: I think this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048272/ios-show-hide-views-inside-a-tableview-cell This works for me.

Comment: okay sir checking